# Use Google Apps Script listbox to select different sheets in spreadsheet

Tags: listbox, google-apps-script

I am currently working with a spreadsheet that has a few years of numerical data across different sheets (also known as tabs by some!?), each sheet/tab representing one year's worth. Following a few online tutorials I have created a simple charts dashboard for any given year. This is a fragment of the code I have so far (except for the portion to draw the charts), with 2 modifications after reading Serge's answer (making "ss" a global and using setActiveSheet).

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID);
ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("2012"));

function doGet() {

  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getMaxRows(),sheet.getMaxColumns());       

  var dashboard = Charts.newDashboardPanel()
     .setDataTable(data)
     .build();

  var uiApp = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("My Dashboard");

  // Dropdown box 

  var listBox = uiApp.createListBox() // Choose data by year
    .setId('listBox')
    .setName('listBox')
    .setVisibleItemCount(1);

  for (i=0; i<ss.getNumSheets(); i++) {  
    listBox.addItem(ss.getSheets()[i].getSheetName());
  }

  var infoLabel = uiApp.createLabel('Select from List').setId('info').setVisible(false);

  // Add a handler to the ListBox when its value is changed

  var handler = uiApp.createServerChangeHandler('showSelectedinfo');
  handler.addCallbackElement(listBox);
  listBox.addChangeHandler(handler);

  // UI Element: Grid

  var mygrid = uiApp.createGrid(1, 3);
  mygrid.setWidget(0, 0, uiApp.createLabel('By Year:'));
  mygrid.setWidget(0, 1, listBox);
  mygrid.setWidget(0, 2, infoLabel)

  var controlsPanel = uiApp.createVerticalPanel().add(mygrid);  

  uiApp.add(controlsPanel).add(dashboard);    

  return uiApp;
}


function showSelectedinfo(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var selectedItem = e.parameter.listBox;
  var listBox = app.getElementById('listBox');
  app.getElementById('info').setText('You selected :'+selectedItem).setVisible(true)
    .setStyleAttribute('color','#008000');

  ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName(selectedItem));

  return app;

}
```

Now I would like to use the dropdown box to select a different sheet, i.e. year, and have charts updating accordingly. However, although I can select a "year" and display it correctly, I am still unable to change to use data from the new sheet. Perhaps any experts here can provide some pointers?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of a way to achieve that. It uses a trick with a label to show results in a customized way  but if you don't need it just keep the ListBox and the handler.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()


function listSelect() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setHeight('100').setWidth('200').setTitle('Select Sheet');
  var p = app.createVerticalPanel();
  var serverHandler = app.createServerHandler('handler').addCallbackElement(p)
  var listBox = app.createListBox() .setId('listBox').setName('listBox').addChangeHandler(serverHandler);  
  var label = app.createLabel('Please select sheet from here').setId('label')
                                      .addMouseOverHandler(app.createClientHandler()
                                      .forEventSource().setVisible(false)
                                      .forTargets(listBox).setVisible(true));
for(n=0;n<ss.getNumSheets();++n){

  listBox.addItem('You are selecting '+ss.getSheets()[n].getName(), ss.getSheets()[n].getName())      
                          }
  listBox.setVisible(false)


  p.add(listBox).add(label);
  app.add(p);
  ss.show(app)
  return app;                     
}

function handler(e){
   var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
   var listBox = app.getElementById('listBox');
   var label = app.getElementById('label');
   listBox.setVisible(false);
   label.setVisible(true).setText('You have selected sheet  '+e.parameter.listBox);
   ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName(e.parameter.listBox));
//   app.close()
   return app;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However as I mentioned at the end, the charts are still not updating correctly? Perhaps you can see some obvious errors now that I have uploaded the relevant bits of my code?

Comment: I made some tests and I get it working when recreating the dashboard in the handler function and hiding the first one... but I'm not sure it's really the right way to go... I hope someone will suggest a better solution for you.

Comment: If you mean creating a different panel for each sheet and changing the visibility, then yeah it does not sound very efficient. :-) Anyway thanks for the suggestions!